# How does Gradle resolve library version conflict?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

In a setup like this:

```
Project
    -ModuleA
        implementation lib:1.1
        implementation project(:ModuleB)
    -ModuleB
        api lib:1.2
    -ExternalJar1
        -lib1.3
    -ExternalJar2
        -lib1.4
```

How does Gradle determine what lib version to select? As per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135182/how-does-gradle-resolve-conflicting-dependency-versions), version 1.4 will be selected because it's the highest version and we have not specified *"any specific constraints for transitive dependencies resolution"*. If that's correct, wouldn't ModuleA code break if it's not expecting a newer version? How can I fix that?

Do external libraries (imported jars) live in a closed sandbox - neither exposing their dependencies to project's classpath, nor using project dependencies in their classpath?
Assuming version 1.3 and 1.4 are not compatible, I can't even force one version as suggested in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444016/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-set-the-same-version-for-two-dependencies), what option do I have to fix this setup?

Comment: Use `./gradlew app:dependencies` to see what the version is in the end. And yes, ModuleA will crash if lib1.4 is not downward compatible.

Comment: Do you have an actual issue or is this question purely academic?

Comment: If it's academic, you should find the answer in the docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html